# How to display an specific item of database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails app has a database set.

```
def index
    @clubs = Club.all
end
```

This is my controller.

If i type in my Index.html.erb

```
<% @clubs.each do |club| %>
<%= club.name %>
<% end %>
```

I get all the names of my database show in my index view.

What if I just want to pick one or just a couple? 
Thru the rails console i can by typing c=Club.find(1) 1 by default takes id=1. 
So how can i just display several ID's and not all one  the database in the same index.html.erb.

thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Let us consider that `params[:ids]` contains all the ids that belong to the records you want to get.

```
def index
    @clubs = Club.where(id: params[:ids])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fix**

The straightforward answer here is to recommend you look at the [ActiveRecord methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) you can call in your controller; specifically `.where`:

```
#app/controllers/clubs_controller.rb
Class ClubsController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @clubs = Club.where column: "value"
    end
end
```

This will populate the `@clubs` instance variable with *only* the records which match that particular condition. Remember, it's *your* Rails app, so you can do what you want with it.

Of course, it's recommended you stick with convention, but there's nothing stopping you populating specific data into your `@clubs` variable

--

**RESTful**

As someone mentioned, you shouldn't be including "filtered" records in an `index` action. Although I don't agree with this idea personally, the fact remains that Rails is designed to favour [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) - meaning you should really leave the `index` action as showing `all` the records

You *may* wish to create a `collection`-specific action:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :clubs do
   collection do
      get :best #-> domain.com/clubs/best
   end
end

#app/controllers/clubs_controller.rb
Class ClubsController < ApplicationController
    def best
       @clubs = Club.where attribute: "value"
       render "index"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
def index
    @clubs = Club.all
end
```

to this

```
def index
    @clubs = Club.find(insert_a_number_that_is_the_id_of_the_club_you_want)
end
```

Querying your database is a complex thing and gives you a ton of options so that you can get EXACTLY what you want and put it into your `@clubs` variable.  I suggest reading [this part of the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

It should also be noted that if you're only going to query your database for one record then change `@clubs` to `@club` so you know what to expect.

Comment: The `index` method should not show only one record. Typically, that is done with another method called `show`, which would have its own template, `show.html.erb`. (Also, you have a typo in your method definition.)

Comment: Great point. @EgeErsoz, Hmgaar - the index action CAN show just one record, but as the above point out it shouldn't point out just one record.  Index is a method designed to list everything as an index, in this case it should index clubs, you should use the show method to show only one record.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to select a specific record or group of records from the database. For example, you can get a single club with:

```
@club = Club.find(x)
```

where x is the id of the club. Then in your view (the `.html.erb` file), you can simply access the `@club` object's attributes.

You can also cast a wider net:

```
@disco_clubs = Club.where(type: "disco") # returns an ActiveRecord Relation
@disco_clubs = Club.where(type: "disco").to_a # returns an array
```

And then you can iterate over them in the same manner you do in your `index.html.erb`. Rails has a rich interface for querying the database. Check it out [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Also note that individual records - such as those selected with the `find` method - are more commonly used with the `show` action, which is for displaying a single record. Of course, that's for generic CRUD applications. It't not a hard rule.